Webscrape table with powershell
My goal is webscrape this page and collect the data in the first table and export as a csv file:
https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/trading/margin-futures-fops.php
Margin Requirements
Chicago Board Of Trade (CBOT):
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/trading/margin-futures-fops.php"

$table = ($WebResponse.AllElements | Where {$_.class -match 'table-responsive'}).outerhtml

However, the query still returns A LOT of HTML.  Is anyone able to shed some light on this to get me closer to my goal?  Thanks in advance.

Your code is retreiving the outerhtml for every table because they all have class='table-responsive' on that page. You might be better starting with $div = ($WebResponse.AllElements | Where {$_.id -match 'cbot'}) which gets the unique parent div for the table of interest, and then extract your csv from the outerhtml of that. However, conventional wisdom says any html processing is best done with a proper html parsing library rather than string manipulation...

Good point re filtering, @mclayton. Note that the page already is properly parsed at that point, and full DOM access is available (thus no need to deal with .OuterHtml - albeit based on the obsolete Internet Explorer engine, available in Windows PowerShell only.

If you want to extract the data from an HTML table, I recommend taking advantage of existing tools others have shared. If you take a look at the powershell module PSParseHtml, it has a function called ConvertFrom-HtmlTable. This module uses other great tools to make this easy as pie for you and I. Thanks PrzemyslawKlys!
We will install the module.
Install-Module -Name PSParseHTML -Force

Then we will extract the HTML with some basic regex. (Benefit of -UseBasicParsing is no longer depending on Internet Explorer components)
$url = 'https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/trading/margin-futures-fops.php'

$content = Invoke-WebRequest $url -UseBasicParsing

$content -match '(?s)<div id="cbot.+?/div>' | Out-Null

Finally, we will pass that selected bit of HTML to the function.
$tabledata = ConvertFrom-HTMLTable -htmlString $matches.Values -all

Now you have the table contents nicely parsed and stored in $tabledata. From there you can inspect it, export it, etc
$tabledata | Format-Table
$tabledata | Out-GridView
$tabledata | Export-Csv -Path \path\to\file.csv -NoType



Thanks a lot for the tips Doug!  Very helpful.  I've never parsed with this module before and sure does make it easier!.
I did have to change the script a bit to make it work.  This was the finished product.
code
$url = 'https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/trading/margin-futures-fops.php'
$content = (Invoke-WebRequest $url -UseBasicParsing).content
$content -match '(?s)<div id="cbot.+?/div>' | Out-Null
$tabledata = ConvertFrom-HTMLTable -Content $matches.Values
$tabledata | Format-Table
$tabledata | Out-GridView
$tabledata | Export-Csv -Path \path\to\file.csv -NoType
code

Glad it helped. The Format-Table and Out-Gridview are for you to look at the data. You don't need them when exporting. Simply do $tabledata | Export-Csv
